# How can I use hr to get full width of his parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have this code and I'm trying to get the hr to start when text start and finish when text ends, is it possible? Actually it only takes the initial width screen

```css
.slider-single {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

hr {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-single">
  <div>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner div to be `inline-block` and add border-bottom to it

```css
.slider-single {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.slider-single > div {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
}
a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-single">
  <div>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
    <a href="#info">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its ok but the hr starts at full width and the idea is it starts with the text

Comment: @Cristian check the update, simply adjust the margin

Comment: I noticed that the line doesnt finish when text finish, it keeps going till the end of the screen

Comment: @Cristian did you add `inline-block` to the div?

Comment: @Cristian well, a copy isn't automatic, you probably have more CSS applied. Can you show me?

Comment: well it's the same but wrapped with a row, i'm using bootstrap aswell

Comment: @Cristian so it's not the same at all .. having bootstrap means a lot more CSS. I can't give you the correct CSS if I don't have all the CSS you are applying

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Christian try this code,

```
<style>
.slider-single {
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0px;
        background: transparent;
    }
  }

 a {
   text-decoration: none; color:red;
  font-weight: 800; margin-left: 3rem;
 }

 hr {
  background-color: blue;   margin-left:4%;
 }

  .links
 {  width:auto;display:inline-block;}
</style>

  <div class="slider-single">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
      <a href="#info">Test</a>
  <hr>
    </div>

</div>
```